# Remapping an array of integers

Tags: python, arrays, function, math

I have an array of integers from [0 .. 255].

I'd like to modify the array so that there are still 256 numbers, but the numbers start from 100 and move up to 255. This means that many integers will be repeating (i.e. [100,100,101,101,102 ...])

Any ideas as to how I can do this? Sorry, I know this is probably a simple problem, but it's really boggling my mind right now...

Thanks!

Note: a solution provided in python, pseudo-code, or javascript would be nice. =)

Comment: What do you mean by **modify the array**: generate new random numbers? replace the old numbers lower than 100 by new random numbers? generate new numbers in an ascending order?

Comment: The criterion you want to use to populate the new array is a bit unclear

Comment: Which numbers do you want to repeat? What pattern should the numbers have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python:

```
RANGE_SIZE = 255-100
for index in range(256):
     array[index] = 100 + int( RANGE_SIZE * float(index) / 255.0 )
```

Sanity check:

- when index = 0, array[index] = 100+0 = 100
- when index = 255, array[index] = 100 + (255-100) = 255

This is linear interpolation. The multiply and divide essentially convert the index range into a linear ramp from 0.0 to 1.0. This is applied as a scale to the desired range width of values, and added to the minimum value.

Comment: Thanks for the added information... I knew there had to be a term for this, but I wasn't sure what it was.

Comment: The real reason programmers need to learn math is so that they can quickly and precisely explain questions like this. Well, either that or figure out the algorithm for themselves.

Answer (score 3):

If you know exactly the numbers you want, why do you need to modify an existing array, why not just make the array you want? Actual Python:

```
nums = [int(i*156.0/256+100) for i in range(256)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
n = 256
nf = float(n - 1)
xs = range(n)
(min, max) = (100, 255)
[min + int(i / nf * (max - min)) for i in xs]
```

gives:

[100, 100, 101, 101, 102, 103, 103, 104, 104, 105, 106, 106, 107, 107, 108, 109, 109, 110, 110, 111, 112, 112, 113, 113, 114, 115, 115, 116, 117, 117, 118, 118, 119, 120, 120, 121, 121, 122, 123, 123, 124, 124, 125, 126, 126, 127, 127, 128, 129, 129, 130, 131, 131, 132, 132, 133, 134, 134, 135, 135, 136, 137, 137, 138, 138, 139, 140, 140, 141, 141, 142, 143, 143, 144, 144, 145, 146, 146, 147, 148, 148, 149, 149, 150, 151, 151, 152, 152, 153, 154, 154, 155, 155, 156, 157, 157, 158, 158, 159, 160, 160, 161, 162, 162, 163, 163, 164, 165, 165, 166, 166, 167, 168, 168, 169, 169, 170, 171, 171, 172, 172, 173, 174, 174, 175, 175, 176, 177, 177, 178, 179, 179, 180, 180, 181, 182, 182, 183, 183, 184, 185, 185, 186, 186, 187, 188, 188, 189, 189, 190, 191, 191, 192, 193, 193, 194, 194, 195, 196, 196, 197, 197, 198, 199, 199, 200, 200, 201, 202, 202, 203, 203, 204, 205, 205, 206, 206, 207, 208, 208, 209, 210, 210, 211, 211, 212, 213, 213, 214, 214, 215, 216, 216, 217, 217, 218, 219, 219, 220, 220, 221, 222, 222, 223, 224, 224, 225, 225, 226, 227, 227, 228, 228, 229, 230, 230, 231, 231, 232, 233, 233, 234, 234, 235, 236, 236, 237, 237, 238, 239, 239, 240, 241, 241, 242, 242, 243, 244, 244, 245, 245, 246, 247, 247, 248, 248, 249, 250, 250, 251, 251, 252, 253, 253, 254, 255]